# Gmail .NET API features

Tags: gmail-api

1) Does GMail API work with free GMail or only with its paid GSuites version.

2) My .NET API client will be limited to sending a few emails a day to a small fixed set of addresses, the emails won't contain any sensitive personal data. Will it be easier for me to implement this with API keys or with OAuth 2?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

- Gmail API can be used with a regular Gmail account, no G Suite version needed. The API [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) though, might vary depending on your account.
- You have to use OAuth, as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) (API keys are usually used to access public resources, which is not the case):

> Requests to the Gmail API must be authorized using OAuth 2.0 credentials.

#### Reference:

- [Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)